# How can I get the current time using timezone offset using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, unix-timestamp, web-frontend

I am using https://openweathermap.org/current api and i want to get current date and time of the target city, I am getting timezone (shift in seconds from UTC) value from api, so how can i get the current time using this timezone offset value.

Lets suppose I have received this below timezone offset value from api

```
const timezone = -14400
```

Comment: Is the time off by your timezone offset vs UTC? Do you an example of actual vs expected results?

Comment: Don't forget time zones!

Comment: What to do with timezone? I am getting timezone from api

Comment: Can you add example API response? Both moment.js (and by extension luxon) can handle instantiating DateTime objects with a specified zone. `new Date(...)` is creating a JS Date object but with your device's time and offset packed in.

Comment: can you share the timeunixvalue  and its actual date value

Comment: 1593674356 is timeunixvalue from api for London and when I am trying to convert it to current datetime using 

**const unix_timestamp = res.data.dt;
const date = new Date(unix_timestamp * 1000);**

I am getting this result
**Thu Jul 02 2020 11:19:16 GMT+0400 (Gulf Standard Time)**
whereas london actual time is 
**8:31 AM
Thursday, 2 July 2020 (GMT+1)**

Comment: In `res.data` is there a specified zone or offset? How do you know it is London?

Comment: The date API accounts for your timezone. It is reflected by four digits after GMT. 
GMT+0400 means that your timezone is roughly 4hrs ahead of GMT. The same time for me is **Thu Jul 02 2020 12:49:16 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)** which means roughly 5hours and 30min ahead of GMT. If you want the time of targeted country use some library that account for timezone date-fns/moment.

Comment: Yes I am getting timezone from api, I searched for London location and got the data for the same, here is the api link https://openweathermap.org/current

Comment: Looks like you get a `"timezone"` in the JSON response, https://openweathermap.org/current#current_JSON. In their example the timezone is `-25200` and `-25200 / 3600 = -7`, so -7 hours from UTC. You can use this to first construct a DateTime objectin UTC then add the hour zone.

Comment: Could you please help me with the code? or can we do it using moment.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const timezone = -14400 //needs to be converted in minutes 
const timezoneInMinutes = timezone / 60;
const currTime = moment().utcOffset(timezoneInMinutes).format("h:mm A");
// 10:10 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

- https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/
- https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

```js
const dt = 1593674356; // unix timestamp in seconds
const timezone = 3600; // zone in seconds

// moment.unix - Unix Timestamp (seconds)
const dateTime = moment.unix(dt).utc().add(timezone, 's');

console.log(dateTime);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: does he really needs a 18kb library for a simple task?

Comment: Do you have a better solution?

Comment: @AzeemAnsari Is that question direct to me or Lfaruki?

Comment: @DrewReese That was for Lfaruki, Actually your above mentioned code didn't work for me, it is giving me object in console with local time zone (Gulf Standard Time), I don't know if I am missing something or making any mistake?